# Sum of 100 digit numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I have two arrays each containing 100 digits.I need to add corresponding digits from units place meaning from the end of the array.If there is a carry it should be added in the next index.It should return another array containing the sum.

Here is my code and something seems to be wrong .Help me

```
void sumOf100DigitNumbers(int num1[100], int num2[100], int sum[101]) {
int i, j = 100, k;
for (i = 99; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (sum[j] == 1)
    {

    }
    else
        sum[j] = 0;

    k = sum[j] + num1[i] + num2[i];
    if (k >= 10)
    {
        sum[j] = k % 10;
        sum[j - 1] = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        sum[j] = k;
    }

    j--;

}


}
```

Method to test it

```
[TestMethod, Timeout(1000)]
    void Test_sumOf100DigitNumbers2()
    {
        int a[100] = {6, 8, 3, 7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 0, 6, 6, 7, 0, 0, 9, 4, 8, 2, 9, 6, 3, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 4, 4, 5, 0, 9, 7, 0, 8, 9, 2, 6, 9, 2, 8, 8, 0, 2, 8, 2, 6, 5, 3, 0, 5, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 3, 6, 0, 7, 0, 9, 9, 0, 4, 6, 4, 0, 4, 5, 1, 9, 5, 1, 5, 3, 6, 6, 3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 1, 6, 9, 2};
        int b[100] = { 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 8, 4, 5, 9, 7, 6, 2, 2, 0, 1, 7, 2, 5, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 8, 7, 3, 0, 2, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 9, 2, 4, 8, 2, 1, 1, 0, 6, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4, 2, 2, 7, 6, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 8, 9, 9, 7, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 9, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0, 1, 6, 6, 9, 7 };
        int ans[101] = { 1, 0, 9, 7, 9, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 8, 2, 8, 9, 0, 2, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 9, 6, 0, 7, 2, 3, 7, 5, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 5, 3, 6, 2, 3, 9, 3, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 8, 8, 9, 9, 6, 7, 9, 4, 8, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 8, 6, 0, 3, 4, 0, 7, 9, 9, 6, 2, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 3, 8, 9 };
        int c[101];
        sumOf100DigitNumbers(a, b, c);
        Assert::AreEqual(true, areEqualArrays(ans, c, 101), L"sumOf100DigitNumbers() failed", 1, 2);
    };
```

but my output is as follows:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgWhr.png)

Comment: I don't know what this is but it's not C. Wanna reformulate your tags?

Comment: It is C edited in visual studio express 2013

Comment: "Something seems to be wrong." The first step when something seems to be wrong is to use a debugger. What did you discover when you used a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Also you probably should make sure `sum` is zeroed out before using it.

Comment: No it is definitively not C. Maybe it's C#.

Comment: `Assert::AreEqual` is not valid C

Comment: `if (sum[j] == 1)` is invalid as `sum[j]` not yet assigned.

Comment: Also, you don't tell HOW it does not work.

Comment: @Raymond Chen i debugged and k assignment is working fine ,but don't know why the same is not being assigned to sum correctly after the operation

Comment: Instead of using the value of `sum[j]` which is indeterminated (it's uninitialized), use a zero initialized variable for the carry and *then* store the result in `sum`. Also, you are testing with a C++ framework, are you compiling your program as C++? Also, using an int to store a single digit is a bit of a waste...

Comment: When you got to `if (sum[j] == 1)` for the first time, did you notice that `sum[j]` has an unusual value?

Comment: @Havenard ignore the test method just look at the first function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize `c`.  This means that its contents are **indeterminate**.  You can't predict what values it will contain.

So when you do this:

```
if (sum[j] == 1)
```

If one of those indeterminate values happens to be 1 then you're performing a carry you don't intend on doing.

You can initialize it as follows:

```
int c[101] = { 0 };
```

Then you can remove this entirely:

```
if (sum[j] == 1)
{

}
else
    sum[j] = 0;
```

Comment: thank you that solved my problem,although i didnt get what was i doing wrong previously .Thank you.

Comment: @Ananthhokage The problem was that `c` was not initialized.  That basically means that the elements of that array start with random values.  If one of those random values happens to be 1, then you perform a carry that you shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you, i never knew that a garbage value can be 1 too.